# Read from txt file not working properly

Tags: java

I'm using this method

```
static void readFile()
    {
        try
        {
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream( "Insurances.txt" );
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( fstream ) );
            String strLine;
            String [] array;
            while ( ( strLine = br.readLine() ) != null )
            {
                array = strLine.split( "," );
                pword++;
                int type = Integer.parseInt(array[0]);
                int tm = Integer.parseInt(array[1]);
                int year = Integer.parseInt(array[2]);
                int month = Integer.parseInt(array[3]);
                int day = Integer.parseInt(array[4]);
                int pass = Integer.parseInt(array[5]);
                double tc = 0;
                if ( type==2 )
                {
                    String man = array[6];
                    String mod = array[7];
                    int cc = Integer.parseInt(array[8]);
                    String lp = array[9];
                    String ex = array [10];
                    boolean extra;
                    if ( ex.equals("true") )
                    {
                        extra = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        extra = false;
                    }
                    insurances[insur] = new CarInsurance( pword, type, tm, year, month, day, pass, tc, man, mod, cc, lp, extra  );
                    tc = insurances[insur].calculateCost( pass, a, insur );
                    insurances[insur].setCost( tc );
                    insur++;
                }
                else
                {
                    insurances[insur] = new LifeInsurance( pword, type, tm, year, month, day, pass, tc );
                    tc = insurances[insur].calculateCost( pass, a, insur );
                    insurances[insur].setCost( tc );
                    insur++;
                }
                System.out.println("y");
            }
            inp.close();
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }
```

to read some info from a txt file and create an object of my LifeInsurance class or my CarInsurance. The reason i use this `System.out.println("y");` is to see whether it completes as many loops as the objects i want to create. When i try to run my programm i only get 7 loops ( 7 y's ) but i need 13. The following is what i have wrote on the txt file :

1,12,2013,6,1,1939

2,12,2008,1,10,1939,Mercedes,E200,2000,AEX32100,false

2,12,2009,1,11,1939,Mercedes,E200,2000,AEX32100,false

2,12,2009,2,10,1940,Fiat,Punto,1400,BIO1245,false

2,12,2009,2,10,1940,Seat,Ibiza,1600,BIE3987,false

2,12,2010,1,10,1940,Seat,Ibiza,1600,BIE3987,false

2,12,2013,6,1,1941,Audi,A4,1600,IXE1256,true

1,12,2008,1,2,1942

1,12,2009,1,2,1942

1,12,2010,1,2,1942

1,12,2011,1,2,1943

2,12,2010,7,23,1943,Renault,Clio,1400,ZIO3890,true

2,12,2011,7,23,1943,Renault,Clio,1400,ZIO3890,true

Could you please help me out because i can't find a reason why it doesn't complete all 13 loops. Thank you in advance.

Comment: How about you try running your code through a debugger?

Comment: The reason is most likely an exception. Instead of `e.getMessage();` do `e.printStackTrace();` and post the output. Also, you can simplify `boolean extra = ex.equals("true");`

Comment: @mre sorry but i don't know how to do that

Comment: "sorry but i don't know how to do that" - then you need to learn it, it's essential in programming. Try Google "using the <name_of_your_ide_here> debugger".

Comment: @jlordo i get y
              y
              y
              y
              y
              y
              y
              java.lang.NullPointerException
                   at LifeInsurance.calculateCost(LifeIn
                   at Demo.readFile(Demo.java:62)
                   at Demo.main(Demo.java:78)

Comment: @AlexandrosSparos: well, which is line 62?

Comment: @jlordo line 62 is `tc = insurances[insur].calculateCost( pass, a, insur );` line 78 in in the main method and it's this `readFile();`

Comment: i bet `insurances[insur]` is `null`.

Comment: @MarcelStör i use textpad and searching <using the textpad debugger> doesn't return anything about the debbuger. Not sure if textpad is an ide though ( as you probably can tell i'm really new at programming )

Comment: @AlexandrosSparos, uuuhhhm, no, Textpad doesn't qualify as IDE, it's a text editor.

Comment: @jlordo but i have initialised an object of the LifeInsurance method and saved it on the array two lines above...how can it be null?

Comment: @AlexandrosSparos: just use some `if`s or a debugger to find the cause of your NPE.

Comment: Where is `a` declared/initialized?

Comment: @jlordo Sorry but i just noticed that my input file is not showing up correctly on the question. It's 13 lines and line 5 and 6 should be sepperated.

Comment: @MichaelFreake yes it was

Comment: @AlexandrosSparos please edit your question to show the lines correctly as well as add the entire stack trace.

Comment: y
y
y
y
y
y
y
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at LifeInsurance.calculateCost(LifeInsurance.java:18)
        at Demo.readFile(Demo.java:62)
        at Demo.main(Demo.java:78)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Demo.main(Demo.java:113)
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: @skoll is correct. The above code is not where the error is occurring, it's happening in your `LifeInsurance.calculateCost(LifeInsurance)` method. Can you please post the code for that method?

Comment: Please do not use DataInputStream to read text, also please remove it from your example and this bad idea is copied often. http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/java-memes-which-refuse-to-die.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should see the line 18 of your LifeInsurance class as suggests your stacktrace:

java.lang.NullPointerException at LifeInsurance.calculateCost(LifeInsurance.java:18)

The data of your 8th line seems to induce something null in the cost calculation.

In order to know if it is an error from inexpected kind of data or a problem in your code, you should first replace 1st line by your 8th and then replace arguments one by one if you don't want to try to debug your code.

(sorry for the "answer" it seems that i cannot add a remark)

Comment: ok i found that i was trying to use a null spot of my array. I fixed that and i got the reading method to work but this time it will run the loop 20 times ( print out 20 y's ). So i changed the while condition to `insur != 13` and placed the `strLine = br.readLine()` inside the loop. Now everything seems to work ok!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have all of your records in `Insurances.txt` on different lines as your data does have 13 distinct records there if one reads closely.

You should also follow what @jlordo is saying and change `e.getMessage()` to `e.printStackTrace()`.  By doing that and running your code, I was getting

Having said that you should also trim all of your strings produced by your `strLine.split(",")` call. For example (without error checking) use this `Integer.parseInt(array[0].trim())` instead of this `Integer.parseInt(array[0])`.

By doing the trim I was able to see the 'y' print 13 times.

Answer (score -1):

You will never get 13 loops if your input file doesn't have 13 lines. Your program is expected to read them one line at a time.

Comment: So what? What I said still holds true.

Comment: No. OP has a `NullPointerException`. He was posting his output file, not his input file...